# What is the meaning of the following XPath fragment?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Im am reading the specifications/documentation of a project and it says:

**You may focus on the following XPath fragment: 
p::= A | * | p/p | p//p | p[q]**

What is the meaning of **p :: = A** ?

Comment: `::=` means nothing in XPath. Perhaps the writer was trying to give a name to a fragment of XPath?

Comment: What does "XPath fragment" is supposed to mean, anyway? I have never met this phrase. Maybe: "An XPath (sub) expression"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what it is getting at is specifying a subset of XPath is supported in this context.

```
p ::= ...
```

is BNF to say `p` is defined by the following grammar.

I assume `A` and `q` are defined similarly, although you haven't given the context.  I'm guessing `A` is an element name, and `q` is a boolean expression (however that is defined).

It's mearly saying that the subset of XPath supported is the following:

- The name of an element (`A`)
- `*`
- Two expressions joined with the / operator (`p/p`)
- Two expressions joined with the // operator (`p//p`)
- An expression with a supported predicate (`p[q]`)

Answer (score 1):

**The provided expression**:

```
A | * | p/p | p//p | p[q]
```

is the *union* of the nodes selected by the individual sub-expressions.

It selects any child element named `A` plus any child elements plus any `p` element that is a child of a `p` element that is a child of the current (initial context) node, plus any `p` element that is a descendant of a `p` element that is a child of the current node, plus any `p` child (of the current node) that has a `q` child.

**It is equivalent to the shorter**:

```
 * | p//p
```

**The specific question asked**:

> What is the meaning of `p :: = A` ?

The XPath expression

```
A
```

selects all children-elements of the current node that are named `A`.